# Where like con argumentos en SQFLITE para Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
final List<Map<String,dynamic>> farmersMap =  await database.query("Farmers", where: "name like '%?%'", whereArgs: [n]);
```

el argumento "n" es una cadena que contiene parte o la totalidad de un campo llamado "name" que existe en la tabla "Farmers".
Probando por mi cuenta en la consulta tradicional de SQL me funciona bien pero en este caso no, sospecho que no le estoy pasando bien la cadena "n" en el parámetro "whereArgs", pero no he encontrado nada que me sirva sobre como hacerlo.

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: @JonathanPerez simplemente me pone <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: Puedes publicar toda la función, para entender mejor el código

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo mediante las rawQuery y pasando los argumentos de una manera específica.

```
database.rawQuery("Select * from Farmers Where name LIKE ? ",['%$n%']);
```